# Session management in angularjs and spring

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, angularjs-directive, spring-session

I am using session service in AngularJS and `@SessionAttributes` in spring. Now how can we link both sessions and track the user session appropriately.

Below is my code:

```
@SessionAttributes("usersessionobj")
public class LoginController { 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("userModel") User user, ModelMap model) {
        /*...*/
        model.addAttribute("usersessionobj",userModel);
        return "result";
    }
}

@RequestMapping("/endsession")
public String nextHandlingMethod2(SessionStatus status){
    status.setComplete();
    return "login";
}
```